# Find element based on a property other than id

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Sorry for the simplicity of the question, or for the clumsiness, but I'm just starting now to use Testcafe/JavaScript.

Now the problem: 
- I want to input a value, in a field, for which the id is dynamically allocated at every browser refresh.
- because the id changes every time, I have to call find the object after some other property
Question: how can I do this, in Testcafe?

Testcafe proposes this code:

```
"2.Type in input": function() {
    act.type("#6287a1e6-prefix", "030");
```

and the property of the object are those: 
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html

Comment: if I would have understood what's in there, I wouldn't have asked here :), but thank you anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a selector to find it based on the `name` attribute:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=Prefix]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the field name is Prefix you can following two methods to get the elements.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("Prefix")
```

which will return NodeList (if element not found will return empty NodeList), you can access elements like elements[0] etc.

OR

```
document.querySelector("input[name=Prefix]")
```

If element not found will return null.